# How do I insert an http link into org-mode with its title?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to have org-mode automatically set the description from the html page's  when inserting a link into org-mode?

Comment: See [Protocols for external access](https://orgmode.org/manual/Protocols.html).

Comment: https://github.com/rexim/org-cliplink will do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a package called [org-cliplink](https://github.com/rexim/org-cliplink) precisely for this.

Alternatively, if you'd like to calculate your own title based on DOM queries instead of using org-cliplink's simple logic that just looks at the `<title>`, here's a simplified version of how I do this in my config:

```lisp
(use-package dash :ensure t)
(use-package s :ensure t)

(defun my-org-link-description (url &rest _)
  "Return link description for URL in the format I use in my notes."
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (require 'dash)
  (require 's)
  (require 'dom)
  (let* ((url ; Use old.reddit.com (the new version is a huge JavaScript mess).
          (replace-regexp-in-string
           "^\\(https?://\\)\\(?:www\\.\\)?\\(reddit.com/r/.+\\)$"
           "\\1old.\\2" url))
         (html-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url))
         (dom (with-current-buffer html-buffer
                (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max) url t)))
         (title (s-trim (dom-text (car (dom-by-tag dom 'title)))))
         (parsed-url (url-generic-parse-url url))
         (host (url-host parsed-url))
         (domain-levels ; E.g. '("com" "ycombinator.com" "news.ycombinator.com")
          (nreverse (-reduce-r-from
                     (lambda (new-part accum)
                       (cons (if accum
                                 (concat new-part "." (car accum))
                               new-part)
                             accum))
                     nil (s-split "\\." host))))
         (path (url-filename parsed-url))
         match-1 match-2) ; Temporary variables for later use.
    (cond

     ;; Reddit comment thread.
     ((and (string-equal "reddit.com" (nth 1 domain-levels))
           (setq match-1 (s-match "^/r/\\([^/]+\\)/comments/" path))
           (setq match-2 (s-match "^\\([^ ]+\\) comments on \\(.+\\)$" title)))
      (let ((subreddit (nth 1 match-1))
            (commenter (nth 1 match-2))
            (top-level-title (nth 2 match-2)))
        (concat "Reddit /r/" subreddit ": " commenter " on " top-level-title)))

     ;; Hacker News comment thread.
     ((and (string-equal "news.ycombinator.com" (nth 2 domain-levels))
           (setq match-1 (dom-by-tag (dom-by-class dom "storyon") 'a)))
      (let ((parent-title (dom-text (car match-1)))
            (user (dom-text (car (dom-by-class dom "hnuser")))))
        (concat "Hacker News: " user " on " parent-title)))

     ;; Pages whose title probably contains the website's name.
     ((setq match-1 (s-match "^\\(.*\\) [-–|:•#·»←] \\(.*\\)$" title))
      (cl-destructuring-bind (_ first-part second-part) match-1
        (let* ((first-longer-p (>= (length first-part) (length second-part)))
               (longer (if first-longer-p first-part second-part))
               (shorter (if first-longer-p second-part first-part)))
          (concat shorter ": " longer))))

     ;; Others.
     (t title))))

(defun my-org-insert-link ()
  "Insert link in the format I use in my notes."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-make-link-description-function #'my-org-link-description))
    (call-interactively #'org-insert-link)))

(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (bind-key "C-c M-l" #'my-org-insert-link org-mode-map))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `org-cliplink` I find the [asamuzaK/url2clipboard](https://github.com/asamuzaK/url2clipboard) browser extension really useful and actually use it more than `org-cliplink` as I can bind the org-mode copying to a key sequence (I use `Alt-o`) which places an org-formatted link in the clipboard then in Emacs its your usual `C-y` to paste into the buffer.

The browser extension is available for Firefox and Chrome based browsers.